# How to use different table view cell class for different UITableView sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

Can I achieve this?

```
if (indexpath.section == 0) {
    // Use Class 1
} else if (indexpath.section == 1) {
    // Use Class 2
}
```

I tried this but not working

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        OneTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"One" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if( cell == nil){
            cell = [[OneTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"One"];
        }
        cell.oneLabel.text = @"HAHAHA";
        return cell;
    }else{
        TwoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Two" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if( cell == nil){
            cell = [[TwoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Two"];
        }
        cell.twoLabel.text = @"HEHEHE";
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain in detail what isn't working.

Comment: Did you register each classes in your `UITableView` with the right identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code that you show, your `oneLabel` and `twoLabel` are never initialized. If you want a quick fix, you can replace both of them with `textLabel`. Something as the following,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        OneTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"One" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if( cell == nil){
           cell = [[OneTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"One"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"HAHAHA";  // Modified
        return cell;
    } else {
        TwoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Two" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if( cell == nil){
            cell = [[TwoTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Two"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = @"HEHEHE";  // Modified
    }
}
```

And you will be able to see different text for two different sections in the table view. And they are indeed different `TableviewCell` classes.

However, if you want to use different labels for different `UITableViewCell`, then you have to make sure that they are initialized somehow somewhere. For example, you could overwrite the default `UITableviewCell` initializer in your custom table view cell. For example, in your `OneTableViewCell.m` file, add the following between `@implementation` and `@end`. In this case, you can use your original code in the `UITableView` class.

```
@implementation OneTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
              reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if ( self ) {
          _oneLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
          [self.view addSubView:self.oneLabel];
    }
    return self; 
}

@end
```